# windows send to in context menu c++

Tags: c++, shell

I added an option to "send to" part in windows context menu named : "A" that runs my c++ program.
when my app runs I need the address of file that user right click on that and choose "A"(my app) in send to part.
how can I do it?
for example in the photo I want new folders address
[image]
thanks

Comment: consider rephrasing the question. Its very hard to read

Comment: If memory serves, the selected files are in `argv`.

Comment: @knightrider got it ?

Comment: @molbdnilo  how? can you make an example please.

Comment: think that : when user clicked on A I want my app to copy the folder into desktop. how can I do it?

Comment: Consider posting the code that you are trying to integrate this with, as it might help people pointing you in the right direction to add the code to do what you require.

Comment: This really belongs on superUser. Short answer: open an explorer window, and enter "shell:sendto" in the address bar. Drag a shortcut to your program into the folder that opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "this is the address:\n";
    cout << argv[1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be an addition to your question and is hence no "answer". Please edit your question accordingly.